# Replace dash between two numbers and after first comma

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm using regex in Notepad++.

I need to replace dash between two numbers and after first comma.

**I have:**

```
ezofhzeifh,0045-6

fejoz-zkdz,2-4656

ceo45zd-45,5454-656

5454-4654,544-97241
```

**and I want:**

```
ezofhzeifh,0045+6

fejoz-zkdz,2+4656

ceo45zd-45,5454+656

5454-4654,544+97241
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show an attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Can the dashes between the digits also occur multiple times after the comma like `ezofhzeifh,0045-6-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
,.*?\K(?<=\d)-(?=\d)
```

And replace it with `+`

Here, `,.*?\K` part matches a comma and some optional text as less as possible and `\K` resets whatever matched and `(?<=\d)-(?=\d)` part matches a hyphen `-` which is preceded and followed by a digit.

Tested and works in Notepad++ v 7.6.1

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJVFZs/1)**

Before replace,

[image]

After replace,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern `,[^\-]*(?<=\d)-(?=\d)` to match the dash between two digits - them simply replace that with a `+`.

Comment: I think you have to take into account that it should be after the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the comma, followed by some numbers, followed by a dash.

```
,\d+\K-
```

Then, replace it with a `+`.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAOv6o/1)